# Proving that the canonical ring morphism $A \rightarrow \prod_{\mathfrak{m} \in \operatorname{spm}(A)} A_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is injective

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring. I’m trying to understand the following proof of the fact that the canonical ring morphism $A \rightarrow \prod_{\mathfrak{m} \in \operatorname{spm}(A)} A_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is injective.

> Let $a \in A$ such that for all $\mathfrak{m} \in
> \operatorname{spm}(A)$ there is $s_{\mathfrak{m}} \notin \mathfrak{m}$
> such that $s_{\mathfrak{m}} a = 0$. Then $\operatorname{Ann}_A(a) \not \subset A$. In particular, $1 \in {Ann}_A(a)$, so $a=0$. Then the
> kernel of the above ring morphism is $0$.

What I’m not sure if I understand is why the kernel of $A \rightarrow \prod_{\mathfrak{m} \in \operatorname{spm}(A)} A_{\mathfrak{m}}$ being $0$ is equivalent to the condition that for all $\mathfrak{m} \in
\operatorname{spm}(A)$ there is $s_{\mathfrak{m}} \in A_{\mathfrak{m}}$ (i.e., $ s_{\mathfrak{m}} \notin \mathfrak{m}$) such that $s_{\mathfrak{m}} a = 0$.

My thoughts: the above map maps the element $a$ to $\prod_{\mathfrak{m} \in \operatorname{spm}(A)}\frac{a}{1}$ (I don’t know how to write this more rigorously), and we assume that $\prod_{\mathfrak{m} \in \operatorname{spm}(A)}\frac{a}{1}=0$… right? But since $A$ is a general commutative ring (not necessarily an integral domain), this doesn’t require that each of the factors must be zero... I don’t see then how to arrive to the condition that there is there is $ s_{\mathfrak{m}} \notin \mathfrak{m}$ such that $s_{\mathfrak{m}} a = 0$ (which I think is equivalent to each factor being zero).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're getting a little mixed up in the product notation on the right-hand side of your morphisms here. We're not looking at multiplying a bunch of elements in a ring here, we're looking at a *product of rings*. For example, if $A=\Bbb Z$, then the map is from $\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb Z_{(2)} \times \Bbb Z_{(3)} \times \Bbb Z_{(5)} \times \cdots$ by sending $z \mapsto (z,z,z,\cdots)$. So the statement that $\prod_{\mathfrak{m}\in \operatorname{spm}(A)} a=0$ really means that $a=0$ in $A_{\mathfrak{m}}$ for all maximal ideals $\mathfrak{m}\subset A$.

Comment: Thank you! This was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

> What I’m not sure if I understand is why the kernel...

This is from the definition of equivalence in a localization. $a/1$ is equivalent to $0/1$ in $R_m$, so there is a $s_m \notin m$ such that $s_m a = 0$.

Now , suppose $a$ is in the kernel of that map, so $a/1$ is equivalent to $0/1$ in $R_m$ for all maximal ideals $m$. Then, $Ann(a)$ contains $s_m$ for each $m$, so is not contained in any maximal ideal, so must be the entire ring.